# Azure Logic App delete Row is not working

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a table that has a composite primary key.

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_FileContainerFiles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FileId] ASC,
    [ContainerId] ASC
)
```

I am trying to delete the row using logic app connector. It works if the primarykey is having one element.

How to input two identifiers in 'RowId' of Logic app. when I tried something like below, Am getting error. Is this a Microsoft logic App Issue? Any Idea. Please help.

[image: Delete Row logic app with two dynamic params at rowId]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. The SQL Connector (which, btw is the same connector used in flows as well as LogicApps and PowerApps) treats primary keys just like SQL. That is, you simply use each key in sequence separated by a comma to construct the "full" key.

My example using composite key:

```
@{join(createArray(items('For_each')?['BUKRS'],items('For_each')?['LIFNR']),',')}
```

TLDR: values separated by comma.

Answer (score 1):

Another working solution is to use instead the "Execute Query" action and do a delete with all the conditions you need.
Sorry for answering such an old post but I had the same issue and found it so I think other people may find it useful too.

Answer (score 0):

The Row Id stands for the unique identifier of the row you wish to delete. 
So if you would like to delete a row based on those 2 input parameters, you would first need to find a way to return you the Row Id (unique identifier) of the row(s) you'd like to delete and then execute the Delete row for each of the returned rows.

Another way would be to use a stored procedure to handle the deletion of the rows.

For Reference: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure of the way how can I send two unique identifiers to RowID. Agree, StoredProc will work, I want to know how to pass two identifiers to RowId.

Comment: The Delete Row action only allows one identifier for RowId. So I'm not 100% sure you can achieve what you want with this action. If you look at the documentation, RowId expects the unique identifier of your table,which is not the same as a primary key. So what you can do is add an  identity-column to your table. Do a "Get Rows" using your FileId & ContainerId to return you the rows that match including the Identity-column. Loop over the result-set of the "Get Rows" and do a "Delete Row" using the Identity-column as value for the RowId.